# How to check each key separately from a list in a loop without creating multiple loops. Which may have a KeyError etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I wrote a code that takes 9 keys from API.
The authors, isbn_one, isbn_two, thumbinail, page_count fields may not always be retrievable, and if any of them are missing, I would like it to be None. Unfortunately, if, or even nested, doesn't work. Because that leads to a lot of loops. I also tried try and except KeyError etc. because each key has a different error and it is not known which to assign none to. Here is an example of logic when a photo is missing:

```
th = result['volumeInfo'].get('imageLinks')  
if th is not None:
    book_exists_thumbinail = {
        'thumbinail': result['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail']
    }
    dnew = {**book_data, **book_exists_thumbinail}
    book_import.append(dnew)

else:
    book_exists_thumbinail_n = {
        'thumbinail': None
    }
    dnew_none = {**book_data, **book_exists_thumbinail_n}
    book_import.append(dnew_none)
```

When I use logic, you know when one condition is met, e.g. for thumbinail, the rest is not even checked.
When I use try and except, it's similar. There's also an ISBN in the keys, but there's a list in the dictionary over there, and I need to use something like this:

```
isbn_zer = result['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers']
dic = collections.defaultdict(list)
for d in isbn_zer:
    for k, v in d.items():
        dic[k].append(v)
```

Output data: `[{'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '8320717507'}, {'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9788320717501'}]`

I don't know what to use anymore to check each key separately and in the case of its absence or lack of one ISBN (identifier) assign the value None. I have already tried many ideas.

**The rest of the code:**

````
    book_import = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        filter_ch = BookFilterForm(request.POST)
        if filter_ch.is_valid():
            cd = filter_ch.cleaned_data

            filter_choice = cd['choose_v']
            filter_search = cd['search']

            search_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?"

            params = {
                'q': '{}{}'.format(filter_choice, filter_search),
                'key': settings.BOOK_DATA_API_KEY,
                'maxResults': 2,
                'printType': 'books'
            }

            r = requests.get(search_url, params=params)
            results = r.json()['items']

            for result in results:

                book_data = {
                    'title': result['volumeInfo']['title'],
                    'authors': result['volumeInfo']['authors'][0],
                    'publish_date': result['volumeInfo']['publishedDate'],
                    'isbn_one': result['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier'],
                    'isbn_two': result['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][1]['identifier'],
                    'page_count': result['volumeInfo']['pageCount'],
                    'thumbnail': result['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'],
                    'country': result['saleInfo']['country']
                }

                book_import.append(book_data)

    else:
        filter_ch = BookFilterForm()
    return render(request, "BookApp/book_import.html", {'book_import': book_import,
                                                        'filter_ch': filter_ch})```
````

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Try reducing your question to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I think giving `None` as default value to the `get` method (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)) could save you some lines of code: `book_exists_thumbinail = {'thumbinail': result['volumeInfo']['imageLinks'].get('thumbnail', None)]}`

Comment: Here I have solved my problem myself. But thanks for your willingness